# Suddenly can't print to network printer--except via telnet/browser connection to port 9100

Tags: windows-7, network-printer

I have a laptop running Windows 7 64-bit and an HP 7310 OfficeJet. I've been printing to this printer for years. It has a fixed IP address on my home network. The printer configuration on my computer sends communications to port 9100 at that IP address, using the RAW protocol, with bidirectional support enabled.

A few days ago, print jobs began to fail. They'd show up in the queue with a status of "Printing" for a short period, but then that would change to "Error - Printing". When I try monitoring what's going on using SysInternals TCPView, I can't catch any process opening up a remote port 9100.

The print failure occurs whatever I'm printing from: Microsoft Word, Acrobat Reader, Firefox. I've rebooted the computer and unplugged and restarted the printer without success.

**However:** When I navigate in a web browser to port 9100 at that IP address, the printer faithfully prints out the HTTP transaction! Likewise, when I open a telnet session to that address and port, the characters I type while the session is open also get printed.

When I have Windows troubleshoot the printer configuration, the only thing it detects is that "sharing the printer HP OfficeJet 7300 series with the homegroup will allow other computers to use the printer". I'm not sharing it with other computers, so that doesn't make sense. Still, I did try that fix, and it made no difference, so I undid it.

No errors or warnings are being recorded in any of the Windows logs at the time I attempt to print.

I have BitDefender, which I haven't configured in any way in the last few weeks, other than to turn on, and then quickly turn off, its disastrous ransomware protection mechanism.

Any ideas on a cause and solution would be appreciated!

Comment: I could envision that a problem with drivers could cause the stated effects.  Try re-installing the HP drivers.  Anti-malware software will sometimes break things.  See if your HP OfficeJet responds to port 80 (with a web browser), and reports any problems.

Comment: I neglected to mention that I had connected to port 80 through a browser, getting the printer's management console. It didn't flag any problems. I'll see about reinstalling the drivers.

Comment: Something sounds wrong if you can navigate to port 9100 and HTTP gets printed but if TCPView isn't showing that connection.  Clear out any documents already in printer queue.  Turn off Windows Firewall if it is safe to do so (you may want to disconnect Internet connection first), in case something got changed there (possibly done by anti-malware software).  Check logs in Event Viewer.

Comment: Clarification: I see the 9100 connection when I'm navigating directly to 9100, but I wasn't seeing it when I was printing from apps.

Comment: I can offhand think of two or three settings that would likely be fixed if you deleted the printer port and then re-installed the printer port by installing the drivers.  (My suggestion wasn't just voodoo.)

Comment: I just installed the latest drivers. Still not working. And I just noticed that the driver thinks the printer's offline. (screaming) That's what it says at the top of the printer queue window: "HP OfficeJet 7300 series - Offline". How can it be offline? When I browse to is port 80, it delivers its management console, so it is obviously finding the network and able to communicate to me, as well as receiving communications from me.

Comment: I did delete the printer from "Devices and Printers", and started from scratch, eventually finding an updated driver from HP from December 2015.

Comment: Sometimes the printer portions like to sleep.  Does the printer have an "Online" button?  If that doesn't fix, try making the OfficeJet just make a copy.  If so, the problem will be narrowed down.  I hope the drivers you installed are closer to 12MB in size than 250MB in size.  HP has been known to release some bloated drivers that actually perform very poorly, but some smaller packages (maybe PCL or PS variations) might work much better in some cases.

Comment: There are no associated errors or warnings in the Event Viewer. I just checked Windows Firewall. No inbound or outbound rules are associated with port 9100. All inbound and outbound entries beginning "hp" or for "File and Printer Sharing" are enabled=Yes and Action=Allow.

Comment: Windows Firewall *also* says "These settings are being managed by vendor application Bitdefender Firewall". Bitdefender Firewall doesn't seem to have anywhere near as elaborate a mechanism for blocking communications; in any event, all the rules it lists are Allow rules except four. The four Deny rules are for Incoming ICMP and ICMPv6, and for Windows Explorer traffic on HTTP and on FTP.

Answer (score 1):

I realized I'd never wrapped this up. Through Bitdefender support, it turned out that they firewall had begun blocking traffic, and I needed to add a firewall rule to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I couldn't find anything in my Bitdefender Firewall settings that would have been blocking print traffic, I turned if off, and my print job went through. So the firewall is the problem, and the block must be on the print driver or something like that, since I know from my telnet/http communications with the printer that it isn't a port block. Sigh. Have I mentioned that Bitdefender repeatedly comes up with ways to upset me?